# See what php page of action returns

Tags: php, forms, post, server, client

For example, in an AJAX call, I would do that:

```
$.ajax({
        type: ...,
        url: bla.php,
        data: ..,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
            ...
```

which would give me what bla.php would return, for example by an `echo`.

How to do that with my form too?

---

So, now my form looks like this:

```
<form action="url.php" method="post">
  Slot:<input type="text" name="slot" value="<?=$varSlot;?>">
  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I see what url.php returns?

Comment: Where should I put that @u_mulder? I've never heard of it.

Comment: Check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/load) hope you are looking for this

Comment: @Saty you are suggesting the same thing with u_mulder. However, it's not clear for me on how to use it. Can you please provide an example with  the `form`?

Comment: I don't quite get what you need, what do you mean by `what url.php returns`? Maybe you just want to include `url.php`?

Comment: @u_mulder when the user presses the submit button, I expect that `url.php` will be executed. Right? Now, inside the `url.php`, I am doing an `echo`. I would like to somehow see on the client side, what was echoed from the server side. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Still not. You've wrote that `success: function(msg) { alert(msg); }` So `msg` is a response from server. You can see what server returns in this js-variable.

Comment: I updated my question @u_mulder. The AJAX call was just an example. In my application, I only use a `form`. How to achieve the same effect with a form, as the one I got with the AJAX call?

Comment: So if you press submit, data will be passed to `url.php` and `url.php` shows it's output.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want @u_mulder. I do not how to receive the output of `url.php` in the client side!

Comment: I give up, I don't understand what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, understand that your form is gonna be redirected to "url.php", you are going to tell the browser to send that form to that page, so it will redirect to that page.

Possibilities
1 - let it be like it is, and in the "url.php" put the code you wanna show, an processe wathever you want

2 - Use ajax instead and retrieve wathever you want to be from "url.php"

3 - If you just want to process the data and get back to the same page you are right now, user redirect("page.php") and it will redirect to that page once it's finished.

4 - Use something like this to make use of ajax and return wathever is in the "url.php" files

```
<form action="url.php" method="post" id="formName">
    SLOT:<input type="text" name="slot" value="<?=$varSlot;?>">
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#formName").submit(function(e){
            $("#id-of-div-or-something").load("url.php");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });    
</script>
```

NOTE: note that the submit function is pointing to a form id, and the "load" point wherever you want to put the codeor wathever is in the other "url.php" page.

Hope it helps

Comment: Why we need `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: the reason is, every form is allways send when you press an submit input or button, the "preventDefault() is a way to tell the browser to prevent that. that way the page does'nt refresh and the you use the "load" to load that page inside anything you want

Comment: there are ways more clear and easier to do this, like, create a button and add a listener to it and only use the "load" stuff that is in the response i gave you